# Bulk insert words in database asp.net MVC Codefirst

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

i have to insert over 70000 words in db, i'm trying to do it codefirst. this is what i did so far but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
protected override void Seed(AnagramBritAZ.DAL.AnagramContext context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
            context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
            var anagrams = new List<Anagram>
            {
                new Anagram { Name = "anagram3"},
                new Anagram { Name = "anagram4"}
            }; // this was for testing to see if adding these works

            List<string> wordslist = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\etc\brit.txt").ToList();

            foreach (string word in wordslist)
            {
                anagrams.Add(new Anagram { Name = word });
            }


            anagrams.ForEach(c => context.Anagrams.AddOrUpdate(p => p.Name, c));
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

EDIT: It seems to work after i waited a few minutes, i'm guessing refreshing the db took longer than i expected. 
The question would be is this the best way to add these 70k+ words to the db?
or is there a better way?
(this was a test for a company as a pre interview)

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: i do update-database in the manager console and there's no error, it takes a few minutes to complete but there's no error, i can't see any new rows in the db after

Comment: i edited the post as well

Comment: Your question is broad. There are many ways to do that, via SQL, a separate controller action, async task, or even client side calls to the server.

Comment: What does `sql profiler` show? We need more context. Table columns, is it Identity auto increment? etc...

Comment: @sabio i want to do it code first and i'm a beginner, so far i've been strugling to do this, and this is the only way i managed to do it, do you know maybe somewhere i could find the other ways you talk about? i guess you could say i meant what's the best way or a beginner, a correct way for code first approach

Comment: @Train i'm not sure about sql profiler, but in rest i need those words to check for anagrams when i input something, so i made the table with ID and Name. Id is auto increment and i was thinking to put the words in the name column. i'm not sure this is the best aproach either, can't really find a lot of examples online with this particular case

Comment: SQL profile would show you the sql generated from EF. That would give you a good idea as to why it's not working, if it's hitting the DB at all.

Comment: ok thank you, i will try to find how to implement that to check :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `AddRange` method.

**Example:**

```
List<string> wordslist = System.IO.File.ReadLines(@"C:\Users\etc\brit.txt").ToList();

var anagrams= wordslist.Select(word=> new Anagram{
    Name = word
    }).ToList();

using(var context= new AnagramBritAZ.DAL.AnagramContext())
{
    context.Anagrams.AddRange(anagrams);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: how about the             context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;   is this the right way? without them it was taking an enourmous amount of time

Comment: Yes. it's better creating a method. if you seed the data the use seed method. otherwise it's no need.context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false; context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; is not required if not use seed method.